# I am stuck with an audio/text thing (using python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, text, wav

I am trying to get all the info of a .wav file by interpreting it as a text file, but using the next code:

```
import wave
w = wave.open('C:/Users/jorge/Desktop/Programas/Python/Datos/Si_Canciones/NSYNC - Its Gonna Be Me.wav', 'r') # :P
for i in range(5000):#w.getnframes()):
    frame = w.readframes(i)
    print(frame)
```

It prints all as I want, but at the end I get something like this:

```
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
b''
b''
b''
b''
#And the b''s continue for a while
```

I would like to add something like this in the for, so I don't get rid off those b''s:

```
    if (something):
        break
```

But I don't know what that "something" could be. Can someone help me with it? :/

(I stay tuned to your answers and wish you a nice week)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious answer would be

```
if frame==b"":
    break
```

But as stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html), there is also a method that gives you the amount of frames; so you might want to use that; enabling you to only iterate through the existing frames. I'm not familiar with the module though.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) (I didn't know that b"" could be a value and less what it means :P)

Comment: b"" means, that you are dealing with a byte string. Look in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) for further information :)